# Bootstrap and panel with nested list produce different list element's height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Reading the Bootstrap quickstart I've created a panel with list group like the one [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels).

It's ok but there are some differences:

1. I need to nest another list
2. I have link inside each list element

Having this in mind this is the result that I get whit this simple panel ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/15aM2Ugb90rL8VaoeRed?p=preview)):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>

  <!-- List group -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Lorem</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Hello world</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Quite correct but:

1. I would that rows containing the words *Morbi leo risus* and *Hello World* will be height as much as all other rows
2. I would that the horizontal line of nested elements will span the entire panel width (like the outer elements)

There's a way to do this just by playing with the element's classes? If no, how can I write a proper CSS (bootstrap's CSS file is quite hard for my dev experience)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the margin and padding of ul,li. and add extra class to the nested li to push the texts. For achieving this, you need to edit bootstrap css and write extra classes.